# Disable Flash Plugin on IE when running test with robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I am trying to run a test on IE with flash plugin disabled. Is there any way I can do it with robot framework?

I've seen other question discussing this on Chrome but couldn't find anything on IE.

Anything would help. Documentation, codes......

My environment setup:

- Internet Explorer(11.0.9600.18697)
- Robot Framework(3.0.2)
- Selenium2Library 1.8.0
- IEDriver 3.0

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436222/selenium-internetexplorerdriver-disable-flash

Comment: @Shubham Jain 

Thanks. But we don't have a budget for Browserstack either.....